# max and min $x y - \ln(x^2 + y^2)$

Tags: calculus

Find max and min

$$x y - \ln(x^2 + y^2) , 1/4 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 4$$

**Problem**: With this hairy expression as my partial derivatives, I do not know what to do.

**Attempt**: [image]  [image]

Comment: just to make this much beautiful you could have removed the portion of that first and second questions... I do not see any reason for you to stop here.... what was the problem?

Comment: How do I continue? Getting started with partial derivatives after some time not doing them.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Transform the expression:

$$xy - \ln(x^2 + y^2) \iff \ln(e^{xy}) - \ln(x^2 + y^2) \iff \ln\left(\frac{e^{xy}}{x^2 + y^2}\right)$$

Now just try to maximize/minimize the $\frac{e^{xy}}{x^2 + y^2}$ using Lagrange Multipler with KKT conditions.

Comment: KKT conditions?

Comment: @jacob [Read More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions). Also you can find more on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
x-\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}=0\\
y-\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}=0
\end{align}

can be combined to, as you have done, to

\begin{align}
(x+y)\left(1-\frac2{x^2+y^2}\right)=0\\
(x-y)\left(1+\frac2{x^2+y^2}\right)=0
\end{align}

and also, since $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$, to
\begin{align}
2xy-2=0
\end{align}

Comment: I thought I was decent in algebra, but I really can't see the hidden algebraic steps here between the first and second expression.

Comment: the answrerer is respectively adding and subtracting your two equations, then factoring.

Comment: There is none. The first expression is the sum of both partial derivatives, the second one the difference. The third one is obtained by multiplying the x-derivative by x and the y-derivative by y and adding both, canceling the normsquare in the fraction.

Comment: Oh you mean the last step, sorry. Now I am confused. The second equation implies $y = x$ (since the second factor on the LHS is never zero). We deduce that the second factor of the first equation is zero. This gives me $x^2 = 1$ or $x = \pm 1$.

Comment: Yes, and since those two points are interior points of the annulus, they qualify for further study. Since the function has a pole towards $+\infty$ at the origin, and no other points with zero gradient exist, they must be minima or saddle points. But better check that with the Hessian.

Comment: What about

$$x-\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{2y}{x}=x^2+y^2 $$

$$y-\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{2x}{y}=x^2+y^2 $$
And so
$y^2=x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}=0,x-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}=0\Rightarrow x^2=y^2\Rightarrow x=\pm y$$

You have to minimize $$xy-\log (x^2+y^2)$$
with given conditions
$$1/4 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 4$$

If $1/4 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 4$ can you find what are the bounds for $x^2$??

If you know what are bounds for $x^2$,

take its minimum value and substitute that in: $xy-\log(x^2+y^2)$

Can you do that now?